# Using Coordinates how to find if a point feature exists at that location in QGIS

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have multiple coordinates stored in list collection.Using those coordinates i am trying to find if a point feature exists at particular location using python.

i tried the following code but not working

```
coordinates = []   #contains multiple coordinates 

for feats in Layer.getFeatures():
    Geom = feats.geometry().asPoint()
    for cords in coordinates:
        if Geom ==  coords:    #from here am not able get it
```

i tried another method too

```
for feats in Layer.getFeatures():
        Geom = feats.geometry().asPoint()
         if Geom ==  coordinates[0]:
          #from here its not working
```

I have gone through all the references but none works

can anyone help me this ....

Answer (score 2):

Your code doesn't work because you cannot use a **QgsPoint** as an object of comparison due to rounding errors. It is more appropriate to use distance for these purposes, with a margin of tolerance (e.g. < 1e-2 m), instead coordinates to avoid a double comparison. So, your code, slightly modified, as follow:

```
Layer = iface.activeLayer()

coordinates = [QgsPoint(388340.0347, 4437148.03305)]   #contains multiple coordinates 

for feats in Layer.getFeatures():
    Geom = feats.geometry()

    for coords in coordinates: 
        dist = Geom.distance(QgsGeometry.fromPoint(coords))

        if dist < 1e-2:
            print Geom.asPoint()[0], Geom.asPoint()[1]
```

it works adequately.

In coordinates list you need to have a list of **QgsPoint** (not a list of tuples of coordinates). **QgsPoint** in above list is the green point in vector layer of following image:

[image]

After running above code at Python Console of QGIS it was obtained one coincidence, as expected, visualized at following image:

[image]

Comment: i am getting all features that exists in a layer using your code, but what i want is i need to store the feature that intersects with the coordinates